# Why `Throwable.detailMessage` is not final?

Tags: java

`Throwable` has following field:

```
private String detailMessage;
```

Why this field is not final. It never be modified except constructor. Even never be accessed except `getMessage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no obvious<sup>1</sup> reason for this in the Java source code for `Throwable` itself.

It is possible<sup>2</sup> that there some code somewhere in the Java SE codebase that needs to be able to modify exception messages using reflection or some other "backdoor" mechanism.  It is also possible that there was in the past, or will be in the future.

But, frankly, it doesn't matter why it was done this way.  *Your* code shouldn't depend on this `private` variable, so it should make no difference to you whether it is `final` or not.

---

<sup>1 - ... to me.</sup>

<sup>2 - I searched the OpenJDK codebase for occurrences of `detailMessage` and some of the hits are consistent with this theory.  Look at `.../hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp`</sup>